# Mysql query - add data from multiple rows with the same id and place them in a table

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have this MySQL table and I want to add the totalUnits and total of the orders with the same clientID.

```
OrderID   clientID     name       pay       totalUnits     total
1            1           A        Paid          2           200
2            2           B        Paid          1           150
3            1           A        Paid          1           100
```

This should be the output

```
clientID     name     totalOrders     totalUnits     totalSales
1             A            2             3               300
2             B            1             1               150
```

When I do the following code, I'm still getting the 3 rows instead of 2. What should I do? Thank you for your help!

```
$orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_orderrecords WHERE pay = 'Paid' AND paymentDate BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'");

foreach($orders as $order){
   $orderID = $order->orderID;
   $clientID = $order->clientID;
   $total = $order->total;

   $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_clients WHERE clientID = '".$clientID."%'");     
           foreach($results as $order){
                  $clientsName = $order->clientsName;
           } 

           $sales = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_orderrecords WHERE pay = 'Paid' AND clientID = '".$clientID."'");
           foreach($sales as $sale){
                  $total = $sale->total;
                  $totalUnits = $sale->totalUnits;

                  $totalSales = $totalSales + $total;
                  $totalProducts = $totalProducts + $totalUnits;
           }  

           $orderItem = array(
                    'clientID' => $clientID,
                    'clientsName' => $cName,
                    'totalOrders' => $totalOrders,
                    'totalProducts' => $totalProducts,
                    'totalSales' => $totalSales
                 );
           $records[] = $orderItem;
}
echo json_encode($records);
```

Comment: I think there's scope to improve considerably on the accepted answer, but not until you've seen (and acted upon) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    clientId,name,
    count(totalUnits) as totalOrders,
    sum(totalUnits) as totalUnits, 
    sum(total) as totalSales 
FROM wp_orderrecords 
GROUP BY clientId,name
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. So can I print the totalUnits? simply echo totalUnits?